# How to iterate through date time range in Java using java.sql.Date and java.sql.Time?

Tags: java, sql, loops, iterator

I had googled to iterate through a datetime range in java, but I just found examples using `LocalDate` or `joda date time`, but I can't find an example using `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Time`.
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you wanting to iterate over? Each day, each hour, each second...etc?

Comment: @JoshChappelle, I want to iterate over each **givenday** in **[startDate , endDate]** and over each minute of the **givenday**, what I like to do is like (just to explain): `for (day between [startDate, endDate]) { for (minute in day) { //code } }`, but using java.sql.Date and java.sql.Time.